# Is there any concept about homeomorphism of two differently labelled graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I already know that there is no isomorphism between two differently labelled graphs but is it also holds for homeomorphism?

Comment: A "homeomorphism" is the name for an isomorphism between topological spaces. Are your graphs topological spaces? How do the labels influence the topology? Or did you mean "homomorphism"?

Comment: I mean homeomorphism that is two graphs are homeomorphic if they can be obtained form a same graph by inserting new vertices of degree 2

Comment: What does differently labelled graphs mean and why can't they be isomorphic?